# How to go through a List of Buttons on JavaFX and show a Scene according to the data of said Button

Tags: java, javafx

I'm making a Movie Theater/Cinema booking system.

I have a List of Buttons set up to show the list of films playing in the Home Page. I am trying to make a function that when we click one of the Buttons in the Home Page, it'll change the Scene where you can see the full details of said movie.

The problem is it always only shows the first movie in my List of movies.

I've tried having some kind of pointer set up to identify each Button.

Here are the objects:

filmPointer starts at 1 because filmNumber starts at 1, also an error will pop up if I set it 0

```
private static List<User> userList = User.getList();
private static List<Film> filmList = Film.getList();
private static ArrayList<Button> allFilmLink = new ArrayList<>();
public static int filmPointer = 1, accountPointer;
```

The function to show the Button with Images on the Home Page:

```
public void filmListContent(){
    mainPane.setContent(filmListPane);

    for (int x = 0; x < filmList.size(); x++) {
        Button listFilmButton = new Button();
        listFilmButton.setPrefHeight(300);
        listFilmButton.setPrefWidth(250);
        int finalX = x;
        listFilmButton.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
            mainWindow.setScene(currentFilmScene); //open film detail
            filmPointer = filmList.get(finalX).getNumberFilm();

        });
        imageFilm = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(filmList.get(x).pathPictureFilm), 250, 350, false, false);
        listFilmButton.setGraphic(new ImageView(imageFilm));

        allFilmLink.add(listFilmButton);
    }
    showFilmLink();
}
```

Here is the code I have on another class where I set up the Scene and it's functions:

```
private void createFilmScene(){
    Text filmTitle = null;
    filmPane = new GridPane();
    HBox titleHB;

    for (int x = 0; x < filmList.size(); x++) {
            if (filmList.get(x).getNumberFilm() == Main.filmPointer) {
                filmPictureStream = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(filmList.get(x).getPathPictureFilm()));
                filmPictureView = new Label("", new ImageView((filmPictureStream)));
                filmTitle = new Text(filmList.get(x).getTitle());

        }
    }

    filmTitle.setFont(Font.font("Times New Roman", FontWeight.BOLD, 30));
    titleHB = new HBox(11);
    titleHB.setAlignment(TOP_CENTER);
    titleHB.getChildren().add(filmTitle);
    filmPane.add(titleHB, 5, 19);
    filmPane.add(filmPictureView, 2, 2, 2, 2); // placement not final
    filmPane.setHgap(5);
    filmPane.setVgap(15);

}
```

If I click on 47 Meters Down, I expect the Scene changes and then details the movie that I click. But it always shows IT Chapter 2.

My Home Page: [Imgur Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtP8N.png)

My Film Details Page when I click on 47 Meters Down: [Imgur Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4E89.png)

Comment: I suggest `ListView` over `HBox`.

Comment: When do you call `createFilmScene()`? It seems to be run before any of the event handlers is invoked... Btw: I strongly recommend not using `static` fields to pass data. It's extremely hard to control the information flow this way. Any update in the wrong order may break your program...

Comment: It is pretty hard to help debug incomplete code, a [mcve] may help you get answers.  In your setOnAction call for each button, you set the scene to `currentFilmScene`, but the code you provided has no reference on how this value is created or updated. Also, running logic with static pointers into arrays is an inherently fragile way of doing things.

Comment: It is usually inefficient to create all scenes up front, you likely only need to create a scene to view info on a film at the time you press the button associated with the film. Or, a [MVVM](https://github.com/sialcasa/mvvmFX/wiki/MVVM-Overview) based arch would associate a reusable single scene for display of movie info with changeable model data instances, with one model instance for each film and where the UI automatically updates with changes in the model data.

Comment: @Sedrick Thank you. I will most likely change a lot of things so I'll try using ListView next time.

Comment: @fabian Thank you for the heads-up about the `static` fields. I've changed the List accordingly so if I add data later it won't break. I call the `createFilmScene()` at the `start` method where I initialize the `mainWindow` and such. I have moved the call of `createFilmScene()` inside `filmListContent()` and it is now showing the results I want.

Comment: @jewelsea I've fixed the problem by calling the `createFilmScene()` method inside the button `setOnAction` event. I've actually read about MVVM while searching for tutorials about scene making but unfortunately I think we're only allowed to manually code everything by the lecturer. At first I used scene builder which was way easier to set up to work with a `Controller` class but I started over when I found out it was not allowed. About the `static` pointers, how should I do it properly? Make a separate method in the `Main` class to call it? Thanks a lot by the way!

Comment: Difficult to advise on design without knowing the app better.  But you could replace `createFilmScene()` with a `FilmPane` class deriving from a layout pane.  On the class, provide a `setFilm(film)` method.  Create a single instance of FilmScene.  On your home page, loop through the list of all films, creating a button acting on each one to set the film in the filmScene, e.g. `for (Film film: films) { Button viewButton = new Button("View film"); mainLayout.add(viewButton); viewButton.setOnAction(event -> filmScene.setFilm(film)); }`.

Comment: @jewelsea That's really good! Thank you! Might have to tinker around a bit to make it work but I will definitely try it later. Now I have to work on other functionality for the app since it's due in a week.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was `createFilmScene()` was called too early(in the `start` method). I coded it that way since I thought the `currentFilmPane` and `currentFilmScene` had to be initialized first before doing anything with it.

Code:

```
public void filmListContent() {
    mainPane.setContent(filmListPane);

    for (int x = 0; x < filmList.size(); x++) {
        Button listFilmButton = new Button();
        listFilmButton.setPrefHeight(300);
        listFilmButton.setPrefWidth(250);
        int finalX = x;
        listFilmButton.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
            filmPointer = filmList.get(finalX).getNumberFilm();
            currentFilmPane = new GridPane();
            FilmPage setFilmPane = new FilmPage(currentFilmPane);
            currentFilmScene = new Scene(setFilmPane.asParent(), 1920, 1080);
            mainWindow.setScene(currentFilmScene);

        });
        imageFilm = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(filmList.get(x).pathPictureFilm), 250, 350, false, false);
        listFilmButton.setGraphic(new ImageView(imageFilm));

        allFilmLink.add(listFilmButton);
    }
    showFilmLink();
}
```